# I add css file in codeigniter but not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Header</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url() ?
>../../assert/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?
>assert/css/bootstap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?
>assert/css/bootstap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
```

This is my code to insert css file in my project but it is not working. My assert folder is in root directory. Please Help me...

Comment: Can you show your information from network tab on devtools?

Comment: are you sure, your files are saved as `bootstap.css`? because, they are actually called `bootstrap.css`... also, it should be called `assets`, assert means something completely different

Comment: try this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). 'css-file-path';?> ">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Make sure you have set the base_url in config.php** examples below
>
> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`
>
> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.somedomain.com/';`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Header</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assert/css/style.css');?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assert/css/bootstap.css');?>">
   
</head>
<body>
```

Also asserts folder make sure is in main directory.

Comment: Just a guess, he also has double typos: "assert" should be "assets" and "bootstap" should be "bootstrap". Also if he loads the uncompressed botstrap.css he shouldn't be loading the minimized one after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs just because of you are not given the correct path
use the below code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assert/css/style.css" />
```

This may solve your problem Thanks